# Networking stackexchange

Tags: support, site-recommendation, site-proposal

I'm not sure if this is the right place to propose but is it ok if a sub-site for networking and telecom questions might be created in the near future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serious networking and telecom questions are both solidly on-topic for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

There've been proposals in the past for a telephony / telecommunications site, but in practice SF seems to cover most of the need.

Comment: thanks, i think this question should be moved to server fault http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333794/networking-difference-between-transport-layer-and-networking-layer

Comment: Doesn't strike me as particularly off-topic, really. You could certainly suggest SF to the author, if he isn't happy with the answers he's received.

Answer (score 2):

You can propose new sites by yourself on [AREA51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). This is the staging site for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Isn't this kind of a dupe with severfault?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on the characteristics of the proposal. OP might give it a try.

Comment: i'll take a look over there